# find a string in all the table or library, schema in db2 iseries as/400?

Tags: ibm-midrange

It can be find a string in all the table or library, schema in db2 iseries as/400?
it should be return the table name, schema name?

the query like:

```
select schame_name, table_name from ??? where value like '%search_string%'
```

Comment: You want to find a string by search every schema, every table in each schema and every column in each table? If that's what you are looking to do, don't do that. Discuss with some senior members of the team the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Yes, I want do that. Thanks for your recomment, i will discuss with my team.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, but it's not a single simple SQL statement...

You'd build a program or stored procedure that queries QSYS2.SYSTABLES to find the schema (library) and table name of every table.

Then for each table, query QSYS.SYSCOLUMNS to get a list of character columns for that table.

Finally, build and execute a dynamic SQL SELECT statement that will check all of the character columns for that one table.

Such a stored proc or program is likely to run for hours if not days.

If you do attempt it, I'd recommend doing so from a program to take advantage of multiple threads/processes.  So you can be running the dynamic SELECT's against multiple tables at once.